# Can an adopted child call birth parents by first name?

Tags: halacha, names, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

Consider someone adopted by Jewish parents, whom he grew up calling 'mom' and 'dad'.  After he reaches adulthood, he meets his biological parents.  Can he call them by their first names, if 'mom' and 'dad' feel uncomfortable?  I know in general one shouldn't call one's parents by their first names.

Comment: Moshe, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. Be sure to remember to check with a qualified rabbinic authority before relying on anything you read here. I look forward to seeing you around!

Answer (score 6):

The Nishmas Avraham ([Chelek Hey Choshen Mishpat Siman 42](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51472&st=&pgnum=49)) and Yalkut Yosef (Kibbud Av Va'em Perek Vov Sif Vov) (among others), rule that an adopted child is obligated in honoring his biological parents. Although there might have been room to say that giving their son up for adoption is considered *mechila* (release) of their right to be honored, they both refute this idea.