# Who should adopted children honor?

Tags: kibbud-av-veim-honoring

Are adopted children obligated to search for their biological parents so they can honor them?  The Talmud implies that an adopted son is not obligated to honor his adopted parents: "Rabbi Aha ben Yaakov raised his daughter's son, Rabbi Yaakov. When he grew up, [the grandfather] said to him: “Give me some water to drink”. He replied: “I am not your son.”" [Sotah 49a]  But the Midrash says: "He who brings up children is called the father, not he who gives birth." [Ex. R. 46:5]  So who should adopted children honor, per halacha?

Comment: More specific: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20171 and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22803. More specific in a different direction: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81720.

Comment: It seems there is no obligation to search for parents to honor them, but only that you should honor then when you know who they are. A Jew needs to appreciate all the good which he receives that includes all parents